# What is the universal covering of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash\mathbb{H}$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane, and $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on
$\mathbb{H}$ by linear transformation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$

I know that one can give a complex structure to $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$, making this a Riemann surface, so that the quotient map
$\mathbb{H} \to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$ is holomorphic.
However, this map is not a covering map (look at $i\in \mathbb{H}$ locally, then this map looks like $z\mapsto z^2$), so
$\mathbb{H}$ cannot be seen as a universal cover of $\mathbb{H}$ via this map.

So my question is: What is the universal cover of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$? By uniformization theorem, is this universal cover holomorphic
(after giving it a complex structure via the covering map) to $\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{H}$ or $\mathbb{CP}^1$?

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)\setminus\mathbb H\cong\mathbb C$ via the $j$-invariant?

Comment: It depends on which category you are working in: If you are working in the category of stacks/orbifolds, then the answer is ${\mathbb H}$. If you are working in the category of Riemann surfaces, then the quotient is simply-connected and the answer is ${\mathbb C}$.